# Google Analytics for mobile site

Tags: google-analytics

Hi I tried searching for information regarding this but get bombarded with other search results, might not be putting in the right question not sure….

Anyways hopefully someone here can help, what I’m having an issue with is my site which has a mobile version that’s separate from the main site, the mobile version can be used by anyone and has a link from the main one but anyone with a mobile device gets redirected to the mobile one. The mobile site is blind to search engines using the nofollow tag on any links that lead to it and hasn’t been cached which is what I want because it would be considered duplicate content, anyone with mobile devices gets redirected to equivalent page on mobile site.

I previously forgot to remove the analytics line from one of these pages and noticed it got cached in the search results so I removed it, which is the issue, how do I know how many people were visiting here (mobile) now etc….  Is there a way to get analytics information without having it go to the search results for duplicate content?

Comment: Is your mobile site on its own subdomain? e.g. m.yourwebsite.com?

Comment: it's in a sub-folder not sub-domain mywebsite/mobile...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem that can be fixed with Google Webmaster Tools, or tagging the content with a rel="canonical", please take a look at:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en

Comment: Just reading up on this and wanted to say thanks for the information

Comment: OK I read the document, not sure if you'll be able to help but I'll give it a shot....

First step was to try to set a preferred site but can't, I'm assuming because it's under a folder....

A 301 redirect doesn't fit because it's not a redirect....

This leaves me with the rel="canonical" in the links, which from reading left me a bit confused some points it sounds like add this to the links you want indexed at other points it sounds like add it to links you don't want too, I'm assuming ones I do want but would like to make sure...

Comment: Another thought is can I add analytics to it and place a rule in the robots.txt file to not index that part. I'm guessing no and that the analytics code would automatically add this to the index?